# How to center text with dynamic length at a give point?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following function which needs to print dynamically generated text(*txt*) centered at a given point(*x,y*)

```js
function printText(x,y,txt) {   
  var s = "";   
  s = "<b style=???>"+txt+"</b>";    
  document.getElementById("some_div").innerHTML = s;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Print how? Are you asking for an animation? Or just the right css rule to center it?

Comment: Get width of text element. Divide by 2. Subtract from x.

Comment: Do you need the center of the element containing the text to be positioned at the given coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `position` of the div `relative` and use `absolute` positioning on the inner element, something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style>
            #some_div {
                postion:relative;
                height:300px;
            }
            #some_div b {
                position:absolute;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function printText(x, y, txt) {   
                var s = "<b style=\"left:" + x + "px;top:" + y + "px;\">"+txt+"</b>";    
                document.getElementById("some_div").innerHTML = s;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="some_div"></div>
        <button onclick="printText(100, 40, 'This is a test');">Click Me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```